# SharePoint 2016 => webdeleted.aspx file not found

Tags: sharepoint-server

I am trying to delete a site collection in SharePoint 2016. Site got deleted but the page that is supposed to show web deleted message ({sitecollectionurl}/_layouts/15/webdeleted.aspx) to the user, doesn't show. User gets a message saying "file not found" instead. Has any one experienced the same issue?
Webdeleted.aspx page exists in _layouts folder and is accessible from site before deletion.

Thanks

Update => I expect to see the following page, but i am getting "404 file not found" messsage instead.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You will get this message if any sub-web is deleted. Upon deletion, you will be navigate to Webdeleted.aspx and go back to site link.

Since your site collection is deleted, you will get file not found message.

Comment: wanted to post this... well yeah, you deleted the site....

Comment: I am trying to delete site collection and there is no subweb in it. Works fine in SharePoint 2013.